# Making a calculation for a modal using coffeescript

Tags: html, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to make it so a user can input 3 numbers and when they click the submit button they will see a modal with the calculations from these 3 numbers within the modal. I am unsure how to accomplish this. I have the calculation in my controller.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def how_much
    @price = (params[:amount])
    @mortgage = (params[:high_rent])
    @rent = (params[:current_rent])

    if @price && @mortgage && @rent.present?
      @monthly_savings = @mortgage - @rent
      @savings_goal = @price*0.03
      @months_to_buy = (@savings_goal/@monthly_savings).to_i
      @total_savings = @monthly_savings * @months_to_buy
    else
      @months_to_buy = 24
      @total_savings = "great savings"
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: {:months_to_buy => @months_to_buy, :total_savings => @total_savings}}
      end
    end

end
```

My form is as follows...

```
      <%= form_tag( '/welcome/how_much', post: true, remote: true) do %>
       <h5 class="label">Estimated new home cost?</h5>
        <%= text_field_tag 'price', nil, placeholder: 'ex. 100,000', class: "form-control form-control-lg" %>

       <h5 class="label">Estimated payment for a new home?</h5>
        <%= text_field_tag 'mortgage', nil, placeholder: 'ex. 1,200', class: "form-control form-control-lg" %>

       <h5 class="label">Current Monthly Rent?</h5>
        <%= text_field_tag 'rent', nil, placeholder: 'ex. 800', class: "form-control form-control-lg" %>

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#savingsModal">
      See how we help
    </button>

<!-- Modal for sign-up -->
<div class="modal" id="savings_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h3 class="modal-title" id="savingsModalTitle">You could be ready to buy in <%= @months_to_buy %> months</h3>
      <h5 class="modal-title">and have <%= @total_savings %>* to put towards a down payment & ...</h5>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Sign-up Now to get started!</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Finally, here is the CoffeeScript I have. It has the calculations as well but I am unsure if I should do the calculations in the CoffeeScript or in the controller. I have no idea if I am doing this right or I am COMPLETELY OFF BASE, PLEASE HELP!!!!

```
# Calculate Savings jQuery
price = document.getElementsByName('house_amount')[0].value
mortgage = document.getElementsByName('high_rent')[0].value
rent = document.getElementsByName('current_rent')[0].value
MonthlySavings: (mortgage, rent) ->
 if mortgage? && rent?
   parseFloat(mortgage) - parseFloat(rent)
SavingsGoal: (price) ->
 if price?
   parseFloat(price) * 0.03
MonthsToBuy: (Savings_goal,MonthlySavings) ->
 if SavingsGoal? && MonthlySavings?
   parseFloat(SavingsGoal)/parseFloat(MonthlySavings)
TotalSavings: (MonthlySavings,MonthsToBuy) ->
 if MonthlySavings? && MonthsToBuy?
   parseFloat(MonthlySavings) * parseFloat(MonthsToBuy)
```

Comment: Is the calculation critical for your business? Like, will that define whether or not the user can get an account? Because if so, the calculation should either be done solely - or at least verified - server-side.

If the information isn't critical, but only nice to have for the user, I would not bother doing it server-side.

Comment: Not critical so I think client-side will work. I need help on how to implement on the client side.

Comment: Additionally: You should consider: If the information isn't critical, why are you collecting it at all?

Comment: I don't need to collect it. Just need it to run a calculation that will show up in a modal on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Calculation
  constructor (@price, @mortgage, @rent) -> 
  monthly_savings -> @mortgage - @rent
  savings_goal -> @price * 0.03
  months -> Math.ceil @savings_goal / @monthly_savings
  savings -> monthly_savings * months
```

And to create the calculaction instance:

```
price = document.getElementsByName('house_amount')[0].value
mortgage = document.getElementsByName('high_rent')[0].value
rent = document.getElementsByName('current_rent')[0].value
instance = new Calculation(price, mortgage, rent)
```

Then to display it somewhere:

```
document.getElementById('total_savings').value = instance.savings();
```

Comment: Ok, so to understand your answer completely. All of this goes in the js.coffee file correct? How do I call the answer in the modal?

Comment: Also, I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` on this line `price = document.getElementsByName('house_amount')[0].value`

Comment: The input is empty when the page loads. Should it only look for the input  when the submit button is clicked? Will that fix the error?

Comment: Ok, so the coffeescript/javascript is throwing an error because on pageload the inputs are empty I can add a line to say if not null but the javascript should check the inputs AFTER they are input by the user. I believe that will fix it and I am still unsure how to send it back to the modal.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with some simpler examples, getting to know how javascript, CoffeeScript and your modals work individually. It's hard to guide you when you seem to struggle to grasp each individual part of your application. But that said, you should only run the `instance.savings()` method once you need it -- that is, when the user presses some button, or takes an action to indicate that he wants the results.

Comment: Ahh, I see so I can call that calculation to run on the button click only. It can collect the data after each change but only run the calculation on button click. So what about running this line of code to get the data and putting a listener in to run the calculation? `$('#mortgage').change ->
  mortgage = $(this).val()`